# How to not stop on imrect MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, callback

I want to get rectangle coordinates from the image being displayed. I want to move images next and back. Here is my MATLAB GUI:

[image]

So when I press <kbd>Next</kbd>, it should display the next image in the series and similar is for the <kbd>Back</kbd> button. I am using this code:

```
function next_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to next (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

    if handles.mypointer ~= length(handles.cur_images)
        handles.mypointer = handles.mypointer + 1;
        pic = imread(fullfile('images', handles.cur_images(handles.mypointer).name));
        handles.imageName=handles.cur_images(handles.mypointer).name;
        imshow(pic);
        h = imrect;
        getMyPos(getPosition(h));
        addNewPositionCallback(h, @(p) getMyPos(p));
        fcn = makeConstrainToRectFcn('imrect', get(gca, 'XLim'), get(gca, 'YLim'));
        setPositionConstraintFcn(h, fcn);
        handles.output = hObject;
        handles.posi = getPosition(h);
        guidata(hObject, handles);
```

But the drawback of this code is that when the <kbd>Next</kbd> button is pressed then it stops on `h=imrect`, so waiting for the user to draw a rectangle. It does nothing if I don’t draw a rectangle. Even if I press the <kbd>Back</kbd> or <kbd>Next</kbd> button again it does nothing, because it is still waiting for the user to draw a rectangle.

How do I not let the program stop at [imrect](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrect.html)?

Comment: Make a separate button for `imrect`...

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

- I think the best practice is to move `imrect` to a separate button, like Excaza mentioned.
- I could not repeat your problem - I created a GUI sample, and all buttons are responsive after `imrect` is executed.
- I also recommend to execute `h = imrect(handles.axes1);` instead of just 'h = imrect;` (I don't know if it's related to your problem).

When I have a problem with a MATLAB "blocking function", I solve it by executing the function inside a callback function of a timer object.
I don't know if it's a good practice; it's just the way I solve it...
Executing a function inside timer callback allows to continue execution of the main program flow.

The following code sample shows how to create a timer object, and execute `imrect` inside the callback function of the timer.
The sample create "SingleShot" timer, and triggers the callback to be executed 200 msec after executing time `start` function.

```
function timerFcn_Callback(mTimer, ~)
    handles = mTimer.UserData;
    h = imrect(handles.axes1); % Call imrect(handles.axes1) instead just imrect.
    % getMyPos(getPosition(h));
    % ...

    % Stop and delete the timer (this is not a good practice to delete the timer here - this is just an example).
    stop(mTimer);
    delete(mTimer);


function next_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % if handles.mypointer~=length(handles.cur_images)
    % ...
    % h = imrect(handles.axes1);

    % Create new "Single Shot" timer (note: it is not a good practice to create new timer each time next_Callback is executed).
    t = timer;
    t.TimerFcn = @timerFcn_Callback; % Set timer callback function
    t.ExecutionMode = 'singleShot';  % Set mode to "singleShot" - execute TimerFcn only once.
    t.StartDelay = 0.2;              % Wait 200 msec from start(t) to executing timerFcn_Callback.
    t.UserData = handles;            % Set UserData to handles - passing handles structure to the timer.

    % Start timer (function timerFcn_Callback will be executed 200 msec after calling start(t)).
    start(t);

    disp('Continue execution...');
```